# i want to save my information eventhought application is terminated?

Tags: iphone

i have used segment control for distance measuring in km or Miles so if i select any option from both and application will terminate and when i start application it should show the lastly used value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several options:

- (the right way) Use NSUserDefaults as drafted in [this tutorial](http://icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/)
- (simple but custom solution) Use a custom plist-file included within your application bundle as drafted in [this tutorial](http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tutorial/how-to-create-an-iphone-preferences-file)
- (bit bloated for such simple case) Use CoreData for persitant storage of your objects / data

Comment: i think you have given the perfect answer of the given question.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Before the O/S terminates your app, it will call the `applicationWillTerminate:` method in your application delegate. If you're asking a more general question -- how to save any information in case of abnormal program exit -- there's no perfect answer for that, and you'll have to give us more context.

Comment: i want to  show value which was last pressed in the segment Control before my application terminates and when i start then it shows me last pressed segment controls value.